# Spring test: countRowsInTable bad result

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-test

I have the following test of Hibernate connection to HSQL database with use of 
 `import static org.springframework.test.jdbc.SimpleJdbcTestUtils.countRowsInTable;`
 
to count rows in table, but after deleting one row the result is still the same. What is wrong with my code ?

**Update: `jdbcTemplate` and Hibernate `SessionFactory` are using the same dataSource bean.**

```
package com.habuma.spitter.persistence;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.springframework.test.jdbc.SimpleJdbcTestUtils.countRowsInTable;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestExecutionListeners;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener;
import org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.habuma.spitter.domain.Spitter;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:persistence-context.xml",
                "classpath:test-dataSource-context.xml",
                "classpath:test-transaction-context.xml"})
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager="txMgr", defaultRollback=true)
@TestExecutionListeners( { DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class })
@Transactional
public class DataAccessUnitTestTemplate {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Autowired
    private SpitterDao spitterDao;

    @Autowired
    private SimpleJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Test
    public void testDataAccess() {

        Spitter spitter = new Spitter();
        spitter.setFullName("First");
        spitter.setEmail("one@gmail.com");
        spitter.setUsername("onefirst");
        spitter.setPassword("password");
        spitter.setUpdateByEmail(false);

        //add to database
        spitterDao.addSpitter(spitter);

        //update user with id = 3
        Spitter toChangeSpitter = spitterDao.getSpitterById(3);
        toChangeSpitter.setFullName("NULL");
        spitterDao.saveSpitter(toChangeSpitter);

        //add next user
        spitter = new Spitter();
        spitter.setFullName("Second");
        spitter.setEmail("two@gmail.com");
        spitter.setUsername("twosecond");
        spitter.setPassword("pass");
        spitter.setUpdateByEmail(false);
        spitterDao.addSpitter(spitter);

        assertEquals(4, countRowsInTable(jdbcTemplate, "spitter"));

        for(int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
            spitter = spitterDao.getSpitterById((long)i);
            System.out.println(spitter.getId() + " : " + spitter.getUsername() + " : " + spitter.getFullName());
        }

        //delete user with ID = 4
        spitterDao.deleteSpitter(4);

        System.out.println("\n");
        for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            spitter = spitterDao.getSpitterById((long)i);
            System.out.println(spitter.getId() + " : " + spitter.getUsername() + " : " + spitter.getFullName());
        }
        System.out.println("Ehm ... " + spitterDao.getSpitterById(4));  //null
        assertEquals(3, countRowsInTable(jdbcTemplate, "spitter")); //assertion ? rows still 4
    }

}
```

This is output

```
1 : habuma : Craig Walls
2 : artnames : Art Names
3 : onefirst : NULL
4 : twosecond : Second


1 : habuma : Craig Walls
2 : artnames : Art Names
3 : onefirst : NULL
Ehm ... null
>>!Assertion!<<
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<3> but was:<4>
```

Comment: It appears that your whole test method is running in the same transaction. If you do a count using hibernate, rather than jdbc I bet you will get the expected answer.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure you get what you expect to get you need to flush the Hibernate session before each assertion. Otherwise some things might get cached in the session and not executed on the database. This way calling Hibrnate functions will return proper results, as it will be aware of the cache, but going around it, directly via JDBC, will not see the cache and return strage stuff.

Comment: The reference manual also hints at this behavior in the [Avoid false positives when testing ORM code](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-tx-false-positives) note in the Testing chapter.